# How to make a plot that connect its points to its closest neighbors?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am working on a code to project a given object onto a plane.

The code works fine (at least it seems like it) in achieving that purpose, the only issue I'm having is in plotting my results.

In the image below, for instance, I'm plotting the projection of a parallelepiped (its edges, to be more precise) in a plane of my choice.

[image]

I would like to make a plot where each point is connected to its closest neighbor. I'm not very confident that this approach would get the job done, but I think it would be worth the shot.

Different ideas to get there are also welcome!

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

Note: I also tried using a solid line style when plotting as opposed to the pixel marker style, but the result I got was not quite what I expected to say the least:

[image]

Comment: The solid line option just connects two adjacent points in your input list, not in the figure. Can you separate your object array into several distinct edges, then plot them with different commands?

Comment: Oh, and I noticed you're missing one edge, the vertical one around x=0.

Comment: @K.Cl I tried separating the object into several distinct edges as suggested and the resulting plot when using a pixel marker style I got the same result. Using the solid line style, however, the plot came out blank.

Comment: @K.Cl Also, thanks for the heads up. I fixed the code so that the edge left out would be included. I'm going to update the images in the question.

Comment: It's weird that the plot was empty in your second try, with the solid lines... If possible, can you add the (x,y) values of the edges you managed to separate to the post?

Comment: A thought that occurred to me is that if you know the vertices before and after your projection, you can plot lines to and from the appropriate vertices, like `plt.plot([x_vertex1, y_vertex1], [x_vertex2, y_vertex2])`.

Comment: @K.Cl, taking a closer look at my code I realized I wasn't really plotting each distinct edge as I thought I was, but upon fixing that and properly implementing that idea, the resulting projection was perfect. Thank you so much for your input!

Comment: Cool! I will post this as an answer so we can signal that this problem is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When telling `matplotlib` to plot a sequence of points and join them with a line, it creates a straight line between two adjacent points in your input data. To create several lines, it's often easier to split your plot command into several ones. An alternative is to arrange your points such that they form the edges you want, but that would be much more complicated in your case.

As discussed in the comments, separating each edge into its own separate `plot` command worked for your case.